# How do I delete a file from the perforce depot?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have a file that I had earlier checked in at my company's depot, but after a lot of re-factoring, I don't need it anymore and need to delete it from the depot, and thereby from my workspace, using the p4v visual client (linux). Is there a way to do this? Right-clicking on the file doesn't show an option to Delete.
Is command line delete the only way to go?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Select the file in the tree view and either right-click and select Mark for Delete, or click the icon with the red X (the 5th one from the left in my version of P4V).

This will mark the file for deletion but will not actually delete it from the depot until you submit your pending changelist.

Note that this performs a logical delete from the depot; the history of the file will still be present and you'll be able to sync to previous versions of the file.  If you want to wipe it completely from the depot along with all its history, you'll need to use the p4 obliterate command which is only available to Perforce administrators.

Comment: Nice answer, but it's worth noting that a file in question must not be checked-out.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem trying to find the mark for delete option, turns out that **you can't have the file checked out** at the same time :) So I had to submit my empty file before being able to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you are using P4V client.

```
if (file is checked out):  
  right-click. revert or submit the file, then  
  right-click. mark for delete  
else:  
  right-click. mark for delete
```

The steps will be similar if you are using command line or any other version management tool